# remove margin from email attached word document

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I have a html page which is attached to the email as word document.

```
string body = String.Empty;
body = new StreamReader("execlude.html").ReadToEnd(); 
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
MemoryStream ms = new new MemoryStream(data);
var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(email.From, email.To);
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "excluded.doc", "application/msword"));
```

Here the attachment becomes word format, but the margin are too big. Let me know a solution to remove margins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you will need to make it a proper word document. 
A beginning: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/how-to-create-word-document-using-C-Sharp/

Answer (score 0):

Brother try these links....

1. [Changing the margins of a Word Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467050/changing-the-margins-of-a-word-document)
2. [Setting word document table cell margin programmatically using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854178/setting-word-document-table-cell-margin-programmatically-using-c-sharp)
3. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/30377e45-6473-4385-a83d-664ad5cc7dea/how-to-set-margin-of-word-document-using-c?forum=worddev